# When creating a Hello World application, it said "This program is blocked by group policy. For more information, contact your system administrator"

Tags: visual-studio-2022

When creating a "Hello World" application using Visual Studio 2022, I have experienced the following error:
"This program is blocked by group policy. For more information, contact your system administrator".

I did contact our IT support, but they do not have any clue on this.

[image]

However, when I create another new application in different folder (e.g. C:\dev\Test4\ConsoleApp2)

The error is gone.

Does anybody ever experience similar issue? How could I troubleshoot with it?

My Visual Studio 2022 professional is in trial period without MSDN license. Does it matter?

Comment: IT Support are the ones that manage and deploy group policy. If you get a brand new laptop off the shelf it'll work fine. As soone as your IT Support applies their group policy it'll stop working

Comment: The problem is only my laptop / account experiences such issues, but not other developers.